# Python split a string w/ multiple delimiter and find the delimiter used

Tags: python, regex, string, split

How to split string with multiple delimiters and find out which delimiter was used to split the string with a maxsplit of 1.

```
import re

string ="someText:someValue~"
re.split(":|~",string,1)
```

returns `['someText', 'someValue~']`. In this case ":" was the delimiter to split the string.

If string is `string ="someText~someValue:"`, then "~" will be delimiter to split the string

Is there a way to find out which delimitor was used and store that in a variable.

PS: someText and someValue may contain special chars, that are not used in split. Eg: some-Text, some_Text, some$Text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string ="someText:someValue~"
print re.split("(:|~)",string,1)
```

If you put in group,it will appear in the list returned.You can find it from `1` index of list.

Answer (score 2):

You may use re.findall.

```
>>> string ="someText:someValue~"
>>> re.findall(r'^([^:~]*)([:~])([^:~].*)', string)
[('someText', ':', 'someValue~')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.findall` to find the none words delimiters using [look around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
>>> string ="someText:someValue~andthsi#istest@"
>>> re.findall('(?<=\w)(\W)(?=\w)',string)
[':', '~', '#']
```